FusionAuth .NET Role Claim Empty
Using the FusionAuth .NET samples (link) and cannot get the roles in the Claims
This seems to be a common issue and appears unresolved. Configured a simple application in FusionAuth with one role.
Logic below from Startup.cs

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie("cookie", options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = Configuration["SampleApp:CookieName"];
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {

                    options.Authority = Configuration["SampleApp:Authority"];
                    options.ClientId = Configuration["SampleApp:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["SampleApp:ClientSecret"];
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");

                    // leave this in, otherwise the aud claim is removed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289426/missing-aud-claim-in-asp-net-core-policy-check-prevents-authorization-but-it for more
                    options.ClaimActions.Remove("aud");

                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["SampleApp:ClientId"]
                    };
                });

        }

   

Checking in Secure.cshmtl
 @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
 {
     <dt>@claim.Type</dt>
     <dd>@claim.Value</dd>
 }


Solved by manually adding the claim in the OnTokenValidated event.
Unsure if this is a bug or if something is missing in the OpenIdConnect configuration or if this is an error on the FusionAuth side but the code below does add the role claims correctly so that
[Authorize(Roles = "MyCustomRole")] can be used in the Controller, or if one needs to use User.IsInRole("MyCustomRole");
FusionAuth to add this to their .NET MVC Template unless there is an alternative configuration option that is missing or a potential bug on the FusionAuth OpenIdConnect implementation.
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
    {
        //** Known Bug - Role Claim getting dropped 
        //** Add Manually from JWT

        if (context?.TokenEndpointResponse?.AccessToken != null && context?.Principal?.Identity != null) 
        { 
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);

            var roleClaims = new List<Claim>();

            foreach (var claim in jwtSecurityToken.Claims)
            {
                if (claim.Type.Contains(JwtClaimTypes.Role))
                {
                    var newClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, claim.Value);
                    roleClaims.Add(newClaim);
                }
            }

            var identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (identity != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaims(roleClaims);
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;

    },

Note the Claim type for the ClaimsIdentity must be ClaimTypes.Role (not JwtClaimTypes.Role)
